# How to increase numbers in filenames by specified value with Windows 10 PowerToys's PowerRename?

Tags: windows-10, regex, batch-rename, powertoys

I've got a bunch of files named as:

```
01. Filename.ext
02. Filename.ext
03. Filename.ext
etc.
```

I need to batch rename them with PowerToys PowerRename by increasing the number in the beginning of the file name by a specific value, say 15, so that their names become, for example:

```
16. Filename.ext
17. Filename.ext
18. Filename.ext
etc.
```

As far as I understand I should use Regular Expressions for this task. Unfortunately it is all I understand regarding this matter.

So I'm asking your help with this exact task: what to put into the "Search for:" and "Replace with:" fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerRename is not the right tool for this type of complex rename.
A more powerful tool is
[Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/),
free for personal use.

For example, I combine below the operations of:

1. Remove the first two characters
2. Prepend an incrementing number starting from 16

[image]

Comment: Why not if it can do the job easier... Thanks a lot for the clue! It works!

Answer (score 4):

### The **PowerShell** option:

```
$Increment = 15
Get-ChildItem | Where Name -match '^(\d+)(.+)$' |
    Select FullName,
           @{ N = 'Index'    ; E = { [Int]$Matches[1] }},
           @{ N = 'NameText' ; E = { $Matches[2] }} |
Sort Index -Descending | ForEach{    
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ( '{0:d2}{1}' -f ( $_.Index + $Increment ), $_.NameText ) }
```

### Breaking it down:

- The [`-match` operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1#-match-and--notmatch) uses [regular expression matching](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html), returns a boolean value & populates the [**`$Matches`** Automatic Variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#matches). The regular expression **`'^(\d+)(.+)$'`** will match any string beginning with one or more digits and at least one character following those digits and generate two capture groups, the leading digits in the first and all subsequent text in the second:

```
PS C:\>>'01. FileName.txt' -match '^(\d+)(.+)$'
True
PS C:\> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              . FileName.txt
1                              01
0                              01. FileName.txt
```

- The [**`-f`** Format operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#format-operator--f) constructs a string using a template and a list of values/varibles. [Format specifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) like the `d2` in `{0:d2}` can add leading zeros among other things:

```
PS C:\>'{0:d2}{1}' -f 7, '. FileNaem.txt'
07. FileNaem.txt
```

- The **[Rename-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Rename-Item?view=powershell-5.1)** Cmdlet's `-NewName` parameter can be either a string or a scriptblock, the scriptblock allowing the new name to be based on the values in the current `$Matches` variable:

```
 { '{0:d2}{1}' -f ( $Increment + $matches[1] ), $matches[2] }
```

Comment: Using BRU seems to be more useful in my case but it looks like I can use your example for adding a copying function to the backup script I use. Thank you!

Comment: Using descending/reverse loop/list, very good idea...

Comment: [@YKKY](https://superuser.com/users/665126/ykky): You're welcome! Hope it helps.

Comment: [@ItWasn'tMe](https://superuser.com/users/969781/it-wasnt-me): Thanks, saw your edit, thanks fre credit there as well.

Comment: What can i do if you deserved it? :)

Answer (score 1):

***// Edit***

Inspired by **[@Keith Miller's](https://superuser.com/users/881098/keith-miller)** idea of ​​using a descending/reverse loop to rename files in cmd/bat:

```bat
set "_n=" & set "_c=" & <nul (for /l %i in (99 -1 16)do set/a "_c=100%~i-15, _n=100%~i" && cmd/v/c "ren "!_c:~-2!.*.ext" "!_n:~-2!.*.ext"")
```

To do the same in PowerShell:

```bat
$i=(ls *.ext).count+16 ; For($i -eq 15; $i--) {
  $old=($i-15).ToString("00") ; ls $($old+'. *.ext')|
  % {ren $_ -new ($_.Name.Replace("$old. ","$i. "))}}
```

***Edit //***

---

```bat
set "_n=" & for /l %i in (1 1 84)do @set "_n=00%~i" && @cmd/v/c "ren "!_n:~-2!.*.ext" "!_n:~-3!.*.ext""
set "_n=" & set "_c=" & >nul (for /l %i in (1 1 84)do @set/a "_c=1000%~i+15" && @set/a "_n=1000+%~i" && @cmd/v/c "ren "!_n:~-3!.*.ext" "!_c:~-2!.*.ext"")
```

You can do this in command line too:

**Obs.:1.** Assuming that when renaming two-digit numbers

**Obs.:2.** Your folder has a total of 84 files = 100 - 16

**Obs.:3.** All files have the same extension.

**1.** First, add a digit to each file, renaming **`16. file.ext`** -> **`016. file.ext`**, thus avoiding conflict when renaming **`01. file.ext`** for the name of **`16. file.ext`** (existing file)

```bat
set "_n=" & for /l %i in (1 1 84)do @set "_n=00%~i" && @cmd/v/c "ren "!_n:~-2!.*.ext" "!_n:~-3!.*.ext""
```

**Obs.:4.** Use **`For /L`** loop from 1 to 84, define **`_n=001`**, when adding 00, in the front variable **`%i`**, a substring of maximum length 2 (file source **`"!_n:~-2!.*.ext"`**) and  a substring of maximum length 3 (file target **`"!_n:~-3!.*.ext"`**) will be used by `ren` for rename your files in loop:

**2.** Use again a **`For /L`** loop from 1 to 84, define **`_c=1000%~i+15`**, when adding 1000, adding to the variable **`%i`**, a substring of maximum length 3 (file source **`"!_c:~-3!.*.ext"`**) and  a substring of maximum length 3 (file target **`"!_n:~-2!.*.ext"`**) will be used by `ren` for rename your files in loop:

```bat
for /l %i in (1 1 84)do @set/a "_c=1000%~i+15" && @set/a "_n=1000+%~i" && @cmd/v/c "ren "!_n:~-3!.*.ext" "!_c:~-2!.*.ext""
```

**Obs.:5.** The result in the loop will be from 1 to 84:

```bat
ren 001.file.ext 16.file.ext
ren 002.file.ext 17.file.ext
ren 003.file.ext 18.file.ext
    ...
ren 084.file.ext 99.file.ext
```

**Obs.:6.** This can easily be expanded to 1 to 840, 1 to 8400, ...:

```bat
for /l %i in (1 1 840)do ...
 ...  set "_n=000%~i" 
 ...  cmd/v/c "ren "!_n:~-3!.*.ext" "!_n:~-4!.*.ext""

for /l %i in (1 1 840)do ...
...  set/a "_c=10000%~i+15"
...  set/a "_n=10000+%~i"
...  cmd/v/c "ren "!_n:~-4!.*.ext" "!_c:~-3!.*.ext"")
```

---

The same in Bat/CMD:

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_n=" & for /l %%i in (1 1 84
)do set "_n=00%%~i" && cmd/v/c "ren "!_n:~-2!.*.ext" "!_n:~-3!.*.ext""

set "_n=" & set "_c=" & >nul (for /l %%i in (1 1 84
)do set/a "_c=1000%%~i+15, _n=1000+%%~i" && cmd/v/c "ren "!_n:~-3!.*.ext" "!_c:~-2!.*.ext"")
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[Cmd /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[Ren | Rename](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Syntax Substring](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)**

  [√] **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

Comment: One definitely should thinking in this language about everything to produce such strings! Really great talent but I'm afraid I should use more obvious ways to prevent asking about every step I take. ) Anyway thanks a lot! At least I'm sure in spite of the fact I will never be able to produce such code myself it is full of explained useful examples I could use with just a little adaptations for my not so frequent tasks.